# Regular expression to remove the key:value from hash / json

Tags: mysql, regex

Suppose I have following json and I want to skip the entry "data_type" from it.

```
{
    "marketing_type":"FIT",
    "controllable":"true",
    "plannable":"true",
    "sbm_qualified":"true",
    "marginal_cost":"{:type=>\"float\", :label=>\"Marginal Cost to steer\",:unit=>\"$/MWh\", :default=>100} must be float.",
    "data_type": "any_value",
    "start_cost":"{:type=>\"float\", :label=>\"Start Cost\", :unit=>\"$\",:default=>0} must be float."
}
```

Expected output is "data_type" entry should be removed from above.

Comment: What language are you working in?  You'd probably be better off actually treating it as JSON and working with it as actual data, removing it through logic rather than string manipulations.

Comment: Try `\"data_type\":\s*\"\w+\",`

Comment: I want to write the sql query, I am doing something like "Update table_name set column_name = column_name (skip the "data_type" field)"

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using regex and string manipulations, and if you're running at least MySQL 5.7, you can use one of the built-in JSON functions, [`json_remove`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove):

```
update table_name set column_name = json_remove(column_name, "$.data_type")
```

Comment: Thanks @James! But I think JSON_REMOVE is added in MySQL 5.7,  I am using MySQL 5.5. Do you have any solution for this ?

Comment: Upgrade MySQL :)

Comment: @ChetanKalore It's probably worth editing your question with further details of what you're doing, and especially the mysql tag, so it gets in front of a better audience for your actual problem.